# How to use Minitest assertions outside of a class?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm trying this:

```
require 'minitest'
Minitest::Assertions::assert_equal(1, 1)
```

Doesn't work:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_equal' for Minitest::Assertions:Module
```

What is the right way? The method [does exist](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/MiniTest/Assertions.html).

Comment: It's an instance method, you are trying to access it directly on the module.

Comment: The module is supposed to be included in a class. Why do you want to call it "outside of a class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module Assertions
  extend Minitest::Assertions

  class << self
    attr_accessor :assertions
  end

  self.assertions = 0
end

Assertions.assert(true)
Assertions.assert(false)
```

The Minitest::Assertions module expects to be able to increment an instance accessor named `assertions`.

http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Assertions.html